# GatsbyJS filter queries by location pathname

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm building a blog with products, each product belongs to several categories. You can click a certain category, and it will take you to a page that only displays products that have that category.

Right now, i'm getting all products on every "category page", and use JS to filter the products, but i want to only load data that i need from the start.

Issue is that the variable that i'm suppost to filter by, is a variable that i compute from location.pathname; (I removed a lot of not relevant code from the snippet)

How can i find a syntax that allows me to add another filter to this query, that uses the "category" variable from this template component?

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    const posts = get(this, 'props.data.allContentfulBlog.edges')
    const edges = this.props.data.allContentfulBlog.edges

    const category = location.pathname

    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>        
      </div>
    )
  }

query categoryPostQuery {
    allContentfulBlog(
      filter: { node_locale: { eq: "en-US" } }
      sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          categories
          date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
          slug              
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am supposed to enter the categories field, which is an array, and check if it includes the "category" variable.

Comment: YAGNI? Do you really need it? You can filter it in render (or fn called from render) before return. IMHO this is unnecessary optimization for static site generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Gatsby's [query variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#query-variables):

```
query categoryPostQuery($category: String) {
    allContentfulBlog(
        filter: { node_locale: { eq: "en-US" }, categories: { in: [$category] } }
        sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }
    ) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                categories
                date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
                slug
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `category` variable can be set using the `context` option in `gatsby-node.js` [createPages](https://deploy-preview-4795--gatsbyjs.netlify.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs):

```js
createPage({
    path,
    component: categoryTemplate,
    // If you have a layout component at src/layouts/blog-layout.js
    layout: `blog-layout`,
    context: {
       category: 'games'
    },
})
```